# Better way to store stock levels for products?

Tags: mysql, optimization, foreign-key, relational-theory, database-size

I currently have 3 tables: `locations`, `products`, and `stock`, which are pretty self-explanatory:

The fields of `stock` are `location_id`, `product_id`, and `quantity`, which is great... until I add a new location (or product, but less so, since the number of locations is normally quite small).

In production, we have 20k+ products, which means that if a new location is created, 200k+ records must be created in stock, which seems quite ridiculous to me. I'm sure it's not *that* bad in reality, but it still feels like something that should be avoided.

So, is there any better way to do this, or is this the normal best practice?

Comment: Well firstly there's really no tangible *number of rows* that matter as far database performance goes, and 200k isn't that many rows. But I don't follow your math or the *why* of it too. What does adding a new `location` have to do with how many `products` you have?...unless you're storing every possible `product` and `location` combination in the `stock` table, with 0 `quantity` for whenever you add a new `location`. If so, that's silly and probably not necessary. But based on the schema you've provided, as far as I'm concerned, adding a new `location` should only result in 1 new row.

Comment: @J.D. Ohhh, I suppose I don't need to make an entry when the quantity is 0 - you're right; that made no sense "^^

Comment: `INNER JOIN` returns no rows for the result when any one of the tables is missing the desired row. `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL`, which can be turned into `0`.  So, even if you need `0`, you don't necessarily need "rows with 0s".  Let's see the `SELECT` if you want to discuss further.